# Importing from PostgreSQL into GeoServer (native src empty)

Tags: postgis, geoserver, postgresql

I'm trying to import data from a table in PostgreSQL into GeoServer, but I'm having a problem calculating the bounds, because the native SRC is not filled in.

My table was previously imported into PostgreSQL from QGIS (SHP) via an sql export.

What is the problem?

I specify that if I import directly the SHP in GeoServer, in this case it works, the native SRC is filled and the layer recognized.

My technical info :

geoserver 2.20.4
pgadmin 6.10
postgis 3.2.1

Answer (score 2):

You will need to use pgsql to `Update` the SRID of all the geometries in your imported table.

[PostGIS – How can you find the CRS (SRID) of your Spatial Data?](https://www.cadlinecommunity.co.uk/hc/en-us/articles/209661629-PostGIS-How-can-you-find-the-CRS-SRID-of-your-Spatial-Data-)  has a good explanation of how to do it

Comment: If I check the SRID of the imported table (select Find_SRID), the value is correct (4326) !

Couldn't it be a question of rights, e.g. geoserver can't select on the content of the database?

Comment: GeoServer will need read, execute rights on the public schema as well as the data schema

Answer (score 0):

Finally, solution found, it was a double problem:

- the geoserver storage wasn't pointing to the right specific schema, by default it was looking in public
- and adding in postgresql the access rights of the geoserver warehouse owner